# Accessing a list that is created in separated Thread from another Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a server that opens two ports and waits for multiple clients to connect to each port. To
simplify it, something like this.

```
public class Server implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
            try{
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port1));
                new Thread1(serverSocket).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException("Error while creating server socket", e);
            }
            try{
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Port2);
                new Thread2(serverSocket).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException("Error while creating server socket", e);
            }
    }
}

public class Thread1 extends Thread{
...
List list; 
}

public class Thread2 extends Thread{
...
}
```

`Thread1` creates `list` that I need to access in Thread2. If I put `Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1(serverSocket).start();` and then access my list with getter Method from Thread1 and pass it as a argument to Thread2 that wouldnt work if I have multiple clients connected.

How do I acces `list` in `Thread2`?

Comment: Why do you create the `List` in the first thread object at first hand? You can move the `List` instance out of the all threads and make it `static` and  `final` if that `List` gonna be a shared object. Then, access through `Thread`s, make it thread safe by using a `synchronized` block. Could you elaborate more on the requirement? then it would be easy make an answer.

Comment: There're many ways you can get this done.